# How could I import private key of my old machine to a new machine?

Tags: ssh, debian, ssh-keys

Yesterday, I've change the hard disk of my laptop. I used it for configure many servers ( I remote them by ssh key).

I've copy id_dsa and id_dsa.pub from the old hard drive to a usb key.

After install my new Debian on my new hard drive, I've put them to /.ssh of my user and try to connect to my server but I had "Permission denied (publickey)".

I've search on the web, and try some solution like change permission with "chmod 600" but it don't works.

Would you have any idea for my problem please ?

Comment: post verbose log from the unsuccessful connection. There should be note why the key was not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you updated your system and also the versions of openssh to 7.x. This version [obsoleted DSA keys](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.0):

> - Support for ssh-dss, ssh-dss-cert-* host and user keys is disabled
>     by default at run-time. These may be re-enabled using the
>     instructions at http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html

If you want to use them, you need to modify your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

or you can specify the command directly on command line:

```
ssh -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss your_server
```

Answer (score 0):

You have reason, the problem was that ssh-dss was disabled.

So, for resolv it, I've create the file config in .ssh folder and insert the line.

Thanks you again.